# filed value is not receiving on server side after submitting asp .NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have three field like this=>

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name, new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.first_name), @autocomplete = "on" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.last_name, new { @style = "border-radius:3px;",@onblur = "FacultyName()", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.last_name), @autocomplete = "on" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.last_name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.faculty_name, new { @class = "control-label" })
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.faculty_name, new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.faculty_name), @autocomplete = "off" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.faculty_name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

that about field created using HTMLHELPER();

and html=>

```
                        <div>
                            <label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
                            <input autocomplete="on" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="First Name Is Required!" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" style="border-radius:3px;" type="text" value="md.kamal" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="first_name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label class="control-label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                            <input autocomplete="on" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Last Name Is Required!" id="last_name" name="last_name" onblur="FacultyName()" placeholder="Last Name" style="border-radius:3px;" type="text" value="chowdhury" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="last_name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label class="control-label" for="faculty_name">Faculty Name</label>
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Faculty Name Is Required!" disabled="disabled" id="faculty_name" name="faculty_name" placeholder="Faculty Name" style="border-radius:3px;" type="text" value="" />
                            <span class="field-validation-error text-danger" data-valmsg-for="faculty_name" data-valmsg-replace="true">Faculty Name Is Required!</span>
                        </div>
```

the problem is I am inserting the first name and last name by hand and wants to insert/set the value of faculty name by automatically means value will be set on basis of first name and last name. and I used jQuery for achieving this
like below=>

```
function FacultyName() {
         $("#faculty_name").val($("#first_name").val() + " " + $("#last_name").val());
         $("#faculty_name").html($("#first_name").val() + " " + $("#last_name").val());
}
```

no I am not facing any kind of problem with this. faulty value is set after providing first name and last name.

[image: Field image]
look above but the problem is started after submitting to the server =>

[image]
I set the value but is still saying value is required! that's the problem?

my controller==>

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "pic_path,first_name,last_name,faculty_name,company_name,city,phone_number,email,zip_code,nationality,sex,religion,blood_group,dob,faculty_active")] Instructor instructor, HttpPostedFileBase pic_path)
    {
        var SupportFileType = new[] { "image/gif", "image/x-png", "image/jpeg", "image/png" };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (SupportFileType.Contains(pic_path.ContentType.ToLower().ToString()) == false)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("pic_path", "Invalid File Type!");
                ViewBag.faculty_active = MyCustomFunctions.UserActivity();
                return View(instructor);
            }
            else if (pic_path.ContentLength > (5 * 1024 * 1024))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("pic_path", "Max File Size Is 5 MB!");
                ViewBag.faculty_active = MyCustomFunctions.UserActivity();
                return View(instructor);
            }

            string pic = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetFileName(pic_path.FileName);
            string CreateNewPath = "~/Content/img/tsms/instructor/" + pic;
            db.Instructors.Add(new Instructor
            {
                faculty_name = instructor.first_name + " " + instructor.last_name,
                pic_path = CreateNewPath,
                first_name = instructor.first_name,
                last_name = instructor.last_name,
                company_name = instructor.company_name,
                city = instructor.city,
                phone_number = instructor.phone_number,
                email = instructor.email,
                zip_code = instructor.zip_code,
                nationality = instructor.nationality,
                sex = instructor.sex,
                religion = instructor.religion,
                blood_group = instructor.blood_group,
                dob = instructor.dob,
                faculty_activation_date = DateTime.Now,
                faculty_active = instructor.faculty_active,
            });
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                if (pic_path != null)
                {
                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/tsms/instructor/"), pic);
                    pic_path.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(null, e.ToString());
                ViewBag.faculty_active = MyCustomFunctions.UserActivity();
                return View(instructor);
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(null, e.ToString());
                ViewBag.faculty_active = MyCustomFunctions.UserActivity();
                return View(instructor);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.faculty_active = MyCustomFunctions.UserActivity();
        return View(instructor);
    }
```

I have gave my full controller? take what you need? don't mess with other stuff.

and my model=>

```
public class Instructor
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First Name Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of First Name Is 50 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last Name Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of Last Name is 50 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////////
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Faculty Name Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of Faculty Name is 200 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Faculty Name")]
    public string faculty_name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Disabled controls do not submit a value. but why are you posting this anyway. Calculate the value in the controllers POST method.

Comment: but why are you posting this anyway => i dont understand what you are trying to say? @StephenMuecke  ....

Comment: Your property should be a get only - that returns the concatenate value

Comment: Stephen is saying there's no reason to calculate this value and try to submit it from the client. You can just send the separate values and populate the model. Then the C# `faculty_name` property can just be defined as `public string faculty_name { get { return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name; } }` That way you don't have to populate it separately, it can just derive the necessary values when needed. The DRY principle applies.

Comment: thanks ... @ADyson ..its really a very good idea...

Comment: no problem. It's a good design principle to think about which pieces of data are actually original from the user, and which pieces of data are just made up of other pieces of data. If you have something just made up of other pieces of data, then you don't have to request it again from the client/user, you just construct it from the other data whenever you need it. Also it means that if the "original" data is changed, your other property is automatically changed too.